# How do I do a subtraction question on turing machine

Tags: turing-machines

For example, 111-11

I want to have the output as 111-11=1

I am a beginner at TM and am having a hard time trying to solve this question.

Comment: try to think of an algorithm that solves your problem

Comment: You might want to study [addition](http://morphett.info/turing/?c636daa95c5a2de1115316aecdf658bc) for a reference first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have unary numbers, so there are three cases to consider: number you subtract from is greater, uqual or smaller, this gives you hint what to handle.

In unary when you subtract 11 from 111 (111 - 11 = 1) you have to delete ones in minuend until subtrahend is 0.
In case these are equal, you have to denote 0 (empty tape might denote this). In the third case, result is negative.

Case 1) 111 - 11 = 11 - 1 = 1 - 0 = 1
Case 2) 111 - 111 = 11 - 11 = 1 - 1 = 0 - 0 = 0
Case 3) 11 - 111 = 1 - 11 = 0 - 1 = - 1

So let us start with first phase: start with scratching from both sides, call it say qS:
'B111-11B' where B is blank, on qS put B at leftmost 1, switch state to qS1, which goes right until it finds B. Moves one to the left, if it is 1, put B and return to the leftmost 1 (say state qSr). After execution:
'BB11-1BB' repeat
'BBB1-BBB' if in state qS1 there is no 1 but -, put B on - and accept.

Case 2 would yield something like 'BB-BB', if you are happy with Blank tape as 0, case 1 solves it already, otherwise put 0 on the tape if there are no 1 left.

Case 3 leaves you with situation like 'B1-11B'. Here only modification is to accept when after - there is Blank. So one step later, there is 'BB-1BB', this is result already.

What could go wrong?
There might be input like 'B11-1-1B', if you are not promised it won't happen. In such case split going right in qS1 into find '-' and then find Blank. If after first '-' there occurs another one, reject on it.

To practice more you could write your code in [simulator online](http://morphett.info/turing/), check addition first as Apass.Jack suggested. When you finish, try multiplication, the sooner the better.

To see a working version look at my [subtraction code at simulator](http://morphett.info/turing/?ad1d0c15ba658b956dccae48ee9dddb1).

This code has format:
state read_symbol write_symbol direction new_state, everything after semicolon is a comment, halt-accept is accepting state, halt-reject is rejecting state * in direction is not move instruction (you may be familiar with S notation or do not really care how it moves, since machine halts now).

```
qS 1 _ R qS1 ; state to start scratching left to -
qS - - R q2 ; check if there is 1 after 1 
qS1 1 1 R qS1 ; pass through 1
qS1 - - R qS2 ; minus found
qS2 1 1 R qS2 ; going for rightmost 1
qS2 _ _ L qSr ; blank found after all 1
qS2 - - * halt-reject ; second minus found, reject bad formatted input
qSr 1 _ L qSr2 ; scratch last 1
qSr - 1 * halt-accept ; scratched 1 at the beginning appears here.
qSr2 1 1 L qSr2 ; leave 1 as is
qSr2 - - L qSr2 ; leave - as is
qSr2 _ _ R qS ; start another pass

q2 1 1 R q2c ; there is a - but still input may be malformed, check it

q2c 1 1 R q2c;
q2c - - * halt-reject ; found second -, reject
q2c _ _ * halt-accept ; there is negative number on tape, accept

q2 _ _ L q2m ; there is only minus left, clean it up
q2 - - * halt-reject ; malformed
q2m - 0 * halt-accept ; accept after cleanup

; tested on accepting -, 1-, -1, 1-1, 11-1, 111-1, 1-11
; testet on rejecting 1--1, 11-11-, --, -1
; to explore it more, maybe -11-11 should give -1111? Not handled now
```

Comment: @Ryan27 updated with working code. My advice is to make comments in your code, or name states with mre meaningful names (qS - starting state, qS1, pass through 1, qSr - r for return, g2m - m for minus) than simply numbers 0, 1, 2 etc. If you could delete your comments (seem obsolete to me right now) that would be awesome. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your help, really helped me alot!